# How to setup ListView that hightlight fits always into it

Tags: qt, qml

I have a vertical ListView with a lot elements. When an element gets clicked a Rectangle pops up under it as highlight.
This doesnt work for the last elements in the ListView, as can be seen in the image.
How do I setup ListView, that a highlight pushes all elements up.

What I have:

[image: What I have]

What I want:

[image: What I want]

Comment: You can use [`contentY`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-flickable.html#contentY-prop) to scroll to a position.

Comment: stucks at boundary doesn't it?

Comment: Oh. Add a spacer at the bottom: `Item { height:500; width:1}`

Comment: You mean a spacer under the ListView, right? Unfortunately this doesn't work with clip:true. If I put clip to false I get ugly overscrolling over the ListView' borders.

Comment: What about setting [`contentHeight`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-flickable.html#contentHeight-prop)  on the `ListView` with`contentHeight: childrenRect.height + 500`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve my issue by expanding the selected delegates height for the while it is selected. Furthermore you have to set the hightlight's y explicitly.

```
ListView{ id:listView
  property var someHeight: 100
  delegate:Item{
    id: delegate
    Connections{
      target: listView
      function onCurrentIndexChanged(){
        if(index==listView.currentIndex)  
          delegate.height=someHeight+listView.highlightItem.childrenRect.height
        else
          delegate.height=someHeight
        }
      }
    }
  }
  highlight:Item{
    z:10
    Rectangle{
      id:highlightRect
      anchors.left:parent.left
      anchors.leftMargin: smallMargin
      anchors.right: parent.right
      anchors.rightMargin: smallMargin
      y: someHeight;
      height:someHighlightHeight
    }
  }
}
```